# choose the column from a cmd command

Tags: command-line, cmd, command, command-prompt

is there a way to choose the columns from windows cmd command?
for example:
 when i use the following  command:

```
tasklist
```

i get this result:

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
System Idle Process              0 Services                   0         12 K
System                           4 Services                   0        920 K
smss.exe                       260 Services                   0        764 K
csrss.exe                      360 Services                   0      3,360 K
wininit.exe                    412 Services                   0      4,428 K
csrss.exe                      424 Console                    1     10,316 K
services.exe                   476 Services                   0      9,116 K
winlogon.exe                   500 Console                    1      5,456 K
lsass.exe                      512 Services                   0     10,300 K
lsm.exe                        540 Services                   0      2,960 K
svchost.exe                    648 Services                   0      8,212 K
svchost.exe                    724 Services                   0      8,048 K
svchost.exe                    796 Services                   0     14,740 K
svchost.exe                    848 Services                   0     60,788 K
svchost.exe                    884 Services                   0     27,812 K
svchost.exe                   1036 Services                   0      9,796 K
```

and i need only for the first and the last column.
is there a way to desplay  only the columns what i need?
tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't perfect as the fields in tasklist vary with the length of the task names, but it may be good enough for you.

It uses a helper batch file called repl.bat from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

```
tasklist|repl "^(.......................).*(.............)$" "$1 $2" m
```

Adjust the length of the first set of (....) to suit you.

Comment: is there a command to desplay the memory of r=each Folder? in windows

Comment: @ofloflofl Did you manage to get it working?  I don't understand your question above.

Answer (score 0):

A big helper is, that the columns have a fixed width, so you can use the following ugly one liner:

```
for /f "delims=" %I in ('tasklist') do @set "_=%I"&@call echo.^%_:~0,25^% ^%_:~64^%
```

or better this batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%I in ('tasklist') do (
    set "_=%%I"
    call echo %%_:~0,25%% %%_:~64%%
)
endlocal
```

the call and %% syntax is my preferred style instead of DELAYEDEXPANSION which I always try to avoid, because it had some annoying side effects in my experience. Therefore I declared it bad style in our department and I'm a bit preachy about it :).